# MacbookPro Trackpad, jumping behavior, hard to control

Tags: osx

I'm using Blender 2.76 on mid-2012 Macbookpro retina, and I have problems with the trackpad when I transform or move objects arounds: it's jumping, and inconsistent, making it nearly impossible to use. It's going back and forth in a very random way.
When I use a mouse, no problem, but it's handy to have to the trackpad sometimes, right?
As any of you experienced this problem? I cannot find any reference to that problem online.

Thanks!

N

Comment: Trackpads are not a good modelling input device, they are very imprecise and prone to error. I would very strongly recommend getting a mouse if you want to model at all seriously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sure of that too. But sometimes, it's just more convenient to adjust things when on the move, and I was wondering if I was the only one to experience this odd behavior.